# MYSQL: Get rows that match criteria

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table that contains users where they have set a minium age and maxium age they want to be shown to.

Table looks like this:

```
=========================================
| id | username | age | minAge | maxAge |
=========================================
| 1  | Clark    | 20  | 16     | 50     |
-----------------------------------------
| 2  | Kent     | 33  | 22     | 25     |
-----------------------------------------
| 3  | Bruce    | 45  | 18     | 25     |
-----------------------------------------
| 4  | Wayne    | 40  | 23     | 45     |
-----------------------------------------
```

- If 'Clark' is logged in, he will see: 'Bruce'.
- If 'Kent' is logged in, he will see: 'Clark', 'Wayne'.
- If 'Bruce' is logged in, he will see: 'Clark', 'Wayne'.
- If 'Wayne' is logged in, he will see: 'Clark'.

No one will see 'Kent', because no one is in his visible range.

How would something like this work?

I have looked at something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE age BETWEEN '16' AND '50';
```

But this of course is the other way around.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE minAge < kentsAge AND maxAge > kentsAge`

Comment: Dear, I don't understand: Clark sees persons with age between 15 and 50? So Clark can see Kent (33 - between 16 and 50), Bruce (45 - between 16 and 50), Wayne (40 - between 16 and 50), am I right?

Comment: Each person sets a min age and max age they what to be visible to. So if lets say Kent(33, between 16 and 50), he would be visible to Clark(age 20). But not Lucy(age 15). 

minAge and maxAge is the range they want to be visible in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `join` on the age column, using `between` (or similar logic).  The challenge is getting the tables in the right order:

```
select u.username, group_concat(tosee.user_name) as users_seen
from table_user u left join
     table_user tosee
     on tosee.age between u.minage and u.maxage and
        tosee.username <> u.username
group by u.username;
```